# Как подключить функцию покупки из Яндекс.метрика Ecommerce в шаблон интернет-магазина?

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день, всем! Есть следующий js код счетчика яндекс метрики в интернет магазине сделанном на storeland:

```html
  <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (d, w, c) {
            (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
                try {
                    w.yaCounter20722519 = new Ya.Metrika({
                        id:20722519,
                        clickmap:true,
                        trackLinks:true,
                        accurateTrackBounce:true,
                        webvisor:true,
                        trackHash:true,
                        ecommerce:"dataLayer"
                    });
                } catch(e) { }
            });
    
            var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
                s = d.createElement("script"),
                f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.async = true;
            s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";
    
            if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
                d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
            } else { f(); }
        })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
    </script>
    <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/20722519" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
  <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

Необходимо сделать подключение Яндекс.метрики Ecommerce функции покупки для товаров. как правильно подключить данную функцию в шаблон?